# how to handle form submissions in Play Framework 2.2.1

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I used the following sample to handle form submission in Play framework 2.2.1. However, play.data doesnt exist any more in play framework 2.2.1. So the sample below doesn't work at all.

Is there a new to handle form submission in play framework 2.2.1?

```
public static Result formSubmit() {
    DynamicForm requestData = form().bindFromRequest();
    String firstname = requestData.get("firstname");
    String lastname = requestData.get("lastname");
    return ok("Hello " + firstname + " " + lastname);
}

java:10: cannot find symbol
[error] symbol  : class DynamicForm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it exists still, but was refactored some time ago... check your imports that should be:

> import [play.data.DynamicForm](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/play/data/DynamicForm.html);
>
> import static [play.data.Form.form](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/play/data/Form.html#form());